# Make available online a localhost web application

Tags: web-services, wamp

I have built a basic web application using html, css and php (it is a library with query, modify etc. capabilities). I have built the databases containing the books information, subscribers information etc. with phpMyAdmin from Wamp server. On localhost (C:\wamp\www) everything works ok (I can add, modify, make queries etc.).

Now I would like to make this web application available online, but I have no idea how this can be done. The access to the database must be also available online (for search, queries etc. from the databases).

Can somebody support me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The access to your database can be local since the php files that use yourdatabase run in the same machine.

You only need to accept online access to your apache server, if it's not accessible yet, and have no firewall active. In this case you should be able to connect to your server by ip. And you'll need a domain and a dns server if you want not having to write the public IP to connect.

You need a public IP address or routing the outside web traffic to your own web server.
Most routers have an advanced section called **IP/Port Forwarding**: find yours. If you don’t have this, I’m afraid you cannot be reachable by the outside.

Besides that, find your private IP with:

```
C:\>ipconfig
```

take note of the **IP address**: that’s your private address, which uniquely identifies you in your local network.

In httpd.conf change:

```
ServerName localhost:80
```

With:

```
ServerName <private IP>:80
```

Also find this line:

```
Require local
```

And change it to:

```
Require all granted
```

Restart your web server. Find out what’s your current public IP address (the public address of your router: https://www.whatismyip.com ) and visit:

```
http://<public IP>:<port>/
```

Or, in case you have not changed the default http port (80) just visit:

```
http://<public IP>/
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I have changed the "localhost" with the private IP (I suppose that this is the "IPv4 Address"), updated the httpd.conf file acc. and restarted wamp.
Please tell me where can I find my <public IP>.
Regarding the IP/Port Forwarding, I have accessed the router and I have found the section "Forwarding". Here there is only a header with no records, but with a button "Add new". If I press it, I need to introduce some information which I do not know:
   - service port (I suppose it is 80, correct?), internal port, IP address, protocol, status, common service port.

Comment: Your public ip is the ip that your router has. It should be the one that they show you when visiting websites like https://www.whatismyip.com

Comment: In the Forwarding section of your router I think you should enter 80 as the ports, your local IP address, HTTP as the protocol, and make sure the status is enabled

Comment: I have done all this and when I try to access the 
    [1]http://router IP
nothing is loaded.

Comment: (Regarding my previous comment, instead of "[1]router IP", I wanted to write "http : //router IP", but I did not understand from the instruction how to write it without http to be removed; <...> did not work).

Comment: The http is removed from your browser's navigation bar but is there. In case your public ip is 88.33.44.55 you should visit http://88.33.44.55/ with the http:// before the ip to check that it's working.

Comment: I have tried, but it does not work (it says: "This site can't be reached").

Comment: Have you followed all the  steps? Can you connect to your private IP instead of the public one? Maybe your computer has a firewall blocking connections from outside

Comment: I have followed all the steps. I'm not sure if in httpd.conf, the following line is correctly written:

ServerName 192.168.0.104:80

With my private IP address, it opens a page with the following info: Wampserver logo and text, "Server configuration" section, "Tools" section, "Your Projects" section and "Your Aliases" section. Is this what should appear?

Is it possible to work with the private IP and not with the public IP?

When I try to connect to the public IP, how does this knows to open a certain html file (my application) as in all the steps performed, there is no link to it.

Comment: Your private ip is working, it's showing the default webpage. You should replace it with your website or redirect to the path your website is. The content of your public ip should be the same. Maybe your router is not redirecting the http traffic to this ip or there is a firewall. The only problem with this ip is that it's a LAN ip. That means it's only accessible from inside your local network and not from anywhere on the internet. If the website should be accessed from internet you should find why your router is not redirecting the traffic or why your computer is blocking the connections.

Comment: At least part of the problem is solved, your apache configuration is working. Now it's only the traffic that comes to your router which is not redirected or can not access your computer. Without this your website can not be accessed from outside your local network.

Comment: I've been seaching for info and I've found this website https://www.simonewebdesign.it/how-to-put-online-your-wampserver/ The only difference I see is that he uses the 8080 port. You could try it also, even though I don't think it should make any difference.

Comment: Now using the "router IP:8080", I get the same result as with the private IP. I suppose that is ok. Adding also the mainpage.html to this path, opens the mainpage of the application, but when I try to interrogate the databases to receive some queries, it gives me the message "This site can’t be reached. localhost refused to connect." Do you know what could be the problem?
Another issue I have is that all the time I restart the router, the IP address changes. In this way, it will be of no use an IP address to somebody online as this IP changes all the time. Can I have a fixed IP?

Comment: Some ip providers offers a fixed ip for your connections, but there are some services like dnsexit.com wich offer you something similar. A program notifies the service of what's your current public ip and it offers you a fixed ip redirected to yours. It's not perfect, but I don't know any other way.

Comment: Additional info to my previous comment: it is not possible to connect to localhost/phpmyadmin except if I write in the address bar "localhost:8080/phpmyadmin". If I change "localhost" with "localhost:8080" in the php file I use to interrogate the database, it still does not work. I think I need to change the port for appache. How do I do this?

Comment: In the meantime, I have found a solution to solve the database access. I have used everywhere port 80 instead of 8080. Thank you very much for your quick and sustained support.

Comment: One more thing. A weird thing is happening. When the router IP address is changed, sometimes it does not work online. With some IP addresses is working online. For example, I had the router IP 79.113.61.200 and it worked perfectly online. Now with addresses 84.232.149.41 or 84.232.149.72, it does not work. Do you know what could be the problem? One remark is that 79.... is an address from the county I am in and 84... are addresses from another county. I do not know if this is affecting somehow the behavior.

Comment: It's really strange. Maybe your internet service provider is blocking some ips, otherwise I don't know what else might be the cause